# Is bzip2 turing complete?

Tags: compression, bzip2, turing-complete

Or any other compression algorithm, for that matter.

(Then again, if there was a turing-complete compression algorithm, would it still be considered a compression algorithm, rather than a programming language?)

Comment: .rar supports a fully featured byte-code.

Answer (score 4):

The question might almost make sense if you had asked about the *de*-compressor, as opposed to the compressor. The job of a compressor is effectively to write a program to be executed by the decompressor that will recreate the original file being compressed. The program is written in the language that is the compressed data format.

The answer to *that* question is no, the bzip2 decompressor is not Turing complete, since it has no way to loop or recurse. Nor does the decompressor for any other standard compression format that I am aware of.

*Update:*

It appears to have since been deprecated due to security concerns, but apparently WinRAR had a post-processing language built into the decompressor called [RarVM](http://blog.cmpxchg8b.com/2012/09/fun-with-constrained-programming.html), which was a Turing-complete machine for implementing arbitrarily complex pre-compression filters for data.

Comment: Rar has RarVM, a turing complete VM for data filtering. The other one is (though not that popular) ZPAQ, which is turing complete as well (I'm not 100% sure on this one).